# Laravel: MySQL auto-updates my updated_at field everyday without any update on article

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I recently worked on a blog application using Laravel 5.4 on my localhost and everything was working fine. However, when I uploaded my application on a remote server on the internet, the updated_at field on every post kept updating automatically every day.

The same code when run on my local machine works fine and the updated_at field is only updated when the post is updated. I am guessing that the problem is at the level of the database configuration but I have no idea how to fix that.

The source code:
migrations

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('featured_image');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->integer('views')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

and I have this in my model Post.php:

```
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```

I am only adding the source code for the benefit of the doubt because it is the same source code that runs on my localhost and produces the desired result.

Comment: You mean no body is updating posts, but updated_at getting updated every day. Make sure if there are any script which is running on schedule is making these updates?

Comment: I think it's because your `views` updated for every view by users

Comment: @MisaGH If that is the case how do I identify and fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `views` field get updated for each view by users.

You can disable updating timestamp fields before increasing view :

```
$obj->timestamps = false;
$obj->views += 1;
$obj->save();
```